# Can a recursive (parsing) function be called concurrently?

Tags: python, recursion, web-scraping, concurrency, scrapy

I've already written some concurrent code for webscraping with asyncio, aiohttp and async/await syntax.
In that situation, I've collected a url-list of all webpages I was interested and supplied it to the event loop throught more or less this example code:

```
futures = [asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url,session)) for url in URLlist]
data_list=[[data[i] for i in range(len(data))] for data in await asyncio.gather(*futures)]
```

Now I've tried to scrape another website were I can't (or at least I don't know how) extract an urlist before starting parsing.
Looking at Scrapy example in [their main page](https://scrapy.org/) I've emulated their follow function (used to extract nextpage-url to feed the crawler) using recursion, in this way:

```
def parse (url):
html=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content,"html.parser")
#... code to extract post information...
nextpage = soup.select_one('a.blog-pager-older-link')
if nextpage is not None:
    nexthref = nextpage.get('href')
    parse(nexthref)
```

It seems to me using the same logic as Scrapy: **you need GET request (I/O waiting) -> html parsing -> find  in the content href url -> recursion**.
But Scrapy (I don't know much about it, so could be wrong) is advertised as be native concurrently library.

But, how can it be concurrent if it needs (at least in the example in their main page) to await for the I/O request before accessing next-page url? 
For the same logic I don't find a way to make my code asynchronous.

Can someone with more insight on the matter give me any advise if it's possible to make it async/concurrent and if that Scrapy example is true async or not?

[Here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links) it seems they are making async the processing(extraction) phase of the code, but isn't the request(GET) phase the one really slowing the code?

Comment: https://github.com/scrapy/queuelib - may be interesting. I think it can't be concurrent when it is relying on the next request data. Scrapy keeps your session and cookies if you want it to. Async and concurrent are not the same thing. You could use your code and make concurrent requests where possible. I don't think there is a magic that allow scrapy to obtain all URLs when it relies on the previous data. Say you have many start urls though in this case it can be concurrent.

Comment: i know async and concurrent are different concept. In this case, I meant to achieve concurrency through async (instead of, for example, parallelism). So you agree that Scrapy example is not concurrent (at least in the slowest part of the code)? I looked at your link but I'm pretty confused how I could exploit it, maybe I don't get it, it's stuff I've never looked at till now.

Comment: Recommend a simple crawler framework: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/spider_examples/toscrape.py

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/coroutines.html and https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/asyncio.html